# Trying to add a ItextSharp List (not the list like list box, but the bulleted list) to a PDF

Tags: .net, silverlight, pdf, itext

I am using an ItextSharp Stamper to load a templated PDF and want to add a bulleted list to a specific location in the PDF.

Fist is this possible?  I have seen in mikesdotnetting blog how to create the list and it looks like what i need.  However, I would like to position the list.

I realize there are a lot of articles and threads about ItextSharp out there, but have not found anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

So I found an answer to my question.  What I did was:

```
        //Used to add Bulleted list to PDF
        PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);

        //Get the coordinates of a text field(PUTLISTHERE) to put the List into
        System.Collections.Generic.IList<AcroFields.FieldPosition> fieldsList = fields.GetFieldPositions("PutListHere");
        AcroFields.FieldPosition fieldPosition = fieldsList[0];

        //Set the coordinates for the list
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(fieldPosition.position.Left, 
                           fieldPosition.position.Bottom, 
                           fieldPosition.position.Right, 
                           fieldPosition.position.Top, 15, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

        //create a new list
        it.List list = new it.List(it.List.UNORDERED, 8f);
        list.SetListSymbol("\u2022");
        list.IndentationLeft = 45f;

        //add the terms to the list
        foreach (Terms_Proposals tp in csaProposal.Terms_Proposals)
        {
            list.Add(new it.ListItem(tp.Term.TermDesc, FontFactory.GetFont("TIMES_ROMAN", 8)));
        }

        //add the list
        ct.AddElement(list);
        ct.Go();
```

Hope this can help someone!